# Send an action with file contents in NgRx / Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I have an effect that an action sent a file over and need to send an action back so that I can update state via a reducer.

```js
@Effect()
    uploadChange$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(OurActionTypes.UploadChange),
        // map(action => action['payload'])
        map(action => {
            // console.log(action['payload']);

            var input = action['payload'];

            const reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = e => {
                const raw = (<FileReader>e.target).result as string;
                const res = JSON.parse(raw);
                console.log(res);
                // this.uploadedSpec = res;
                //  return of(new UploadComplete(res));
            }

            reader.readAsText(input);
        }),
        map((res) => new OurActions.UploadComplete(res))
    );
```

I cannot quite figure out a way to send the results of the upload to the action OurActions.UploadComplete. The way above has res as `underfined`. Needing help with this one thing.

Answer (score 0):

Use some thing like this:

```
return this.searchService.searchByCriteria(search).pipe(
  map(result => //have an flag in the backend code
   !!result.success ? new fromActions.successAction(result) :
    new fromActions.failureAction(result),
  ),
  catchError(error => of(new errorActions.SystemError(error))),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to `flatMap` to your desired reader result already?

```
flatMap(({ payload }) => new Observable(obs => {
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onerror = err => obs.error(err);
  reader.onload = () => {
    obs.next(JSON.parse(reader.result as string));
    obs.complete();
  };
  reader.readAsText(payload);
})
```

The `FileReader` API is indeed async so you have to consider it when implementing your operator pipelines. The `map` operator does not handle any
async contexts, which `flatMap` (aka. `mergeMap`) does. It will actually do the exact same thing as the `map` operator, but with the value returned by the `Observable` you're required to provide when using the `flatMap` operator. This would also work with promises as you could easily transform any `Promise` into an `Observable` by calling the `fromPromise` factory function.